# Did the lords know the truth?

Tags: game-of-thrones, character-motivation

At the last episode of Game of Thrones the council of the lords of Westeros is summoned and they

> elect Bran the Broken as the new king of the Six Kingdoms.

When they do that, is the fact that Jon

> is the true heir to the throne, through Aegon Targaryen

known to them?

We know Samwell and Starks know. But what about the others?

Comment: I think we can safely say at this point that none of them cares in the slightest about the Targaryen "right" to the throne, they just want a good king. Not to mention that electing Jon would only result in Jon's execution and yet another slaughter.

Comment: Well, one episode ago, Varys was writing everybody about it, so it seems like a break in continuity...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of now, it is unknown whether they divulged the truth of Jon's parentage to anyone else in Westeros. The only living people we, the audience, know to know this truth are the following:

- Sansa Stark
- Arya Stark
- Bran Stark
- Tyrion Lannister
- Jon Snow
- Samwell Tarly

It seems, at least for now, this fact will remain with these people unless the show writers tell us otherwise.

Comment: Uhm, Sam? Also possibly Gilly, despite Sam's firm efforts to erase her from this particular historical footnote.

Comment: Whoops, forgot about my boy Sam :-) Edited my mistake.

Comment: Gilly is just not going to get her due!

Comment: I left her out because it's unknown whether Sam told her or not.

Comment: She discovered it in the first place! But yes, she might not have been aware what it meant. (I bet she figured it out about 5 minutes later but just didn't care.)

Comment: She only figured out that Rhaegar had his marriage to Elia Martel annulled. The High Septon's diary never mentioned Lyanna Stark by name. The only reason Sam figured out that meant Lyanna Stark was because he is well-versed in Westerosi history, while Gilly is most likely not (at that point at least).